# jQuery Remove CSS Class from all elements in TreeView not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET TreeView control and at certain times a CSS class is added to `span` elements to alert client-side code to disable the checkboxes in the tree. Done and working.

The problem is the `CSS` class acts as a flag to disable checkboxes and needs to be removed. The jQuery to preform this seems straight forward.

I have read the following and it seemed like an obvious solution:
[jQuery Remove CSS Class from all Descendants at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462958/jquery-remove-css-class-from-all-descendants-at-once)

Here is the rendered source (part of it - the TreeView is huge, just know these `<span>` elements are descendants of the TreeView:

```
<div id="MainContent_MyTreeView">
   .....
      <span class="disabledTreeviewNode">
```

So I have the following `jQuery` *which is being hit* client side when needed to remove this class:

```
  function EnableAllCheckBoxes(treeviewClientID) {
     $(treeviewClientID).removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');
  }
```

I also have tried variations like:

```
$(treeviewClientID + ' span').removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');
```

and:

```
$(treeviewClientID + ' span').removeClass();
```

and:

```
$(treeviewClientID).removeClass();
```

Unfortunately after I inspect the page and the jQuery runs, the class has not been removed:

```
<div id="MainContent_MyTreeView" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)">
    <table style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <div id="MainContent_MyTreeViewn0Nodes" style="display: block;">
        <table style="border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="MainContent_MyTreeViewn1CheckBox" id="MainContent_MyTreeViewn1CheckBox" type="checkbox"/>
                            <span id="MainContent_MyTreeViewst1" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">
                                <span class="disabledTreeviewNode">
                                    Text - My Description
```

The class I need removed is as follows in that bottom `<span>`

`<span class="disabledTreeviewNode">`

I also have tried the following which didn't work either:

```
     **$(treeviewClientID + ' span').filter(function () {
        return $(this);
     }).removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');**
```

The value `treeviewClientID` is correct because I have used it to manipulate other parts of the tree so that value is working and correct.

Any idea on why that class is not removed on the child `<span>` elements in the TreeView control, or what I might be doing incorrectly?

**EDIT:** Added full HTML down to `<span>` that has class not being removed.

Comment: Are the spans direct descendants of `MainContent` or are they deeper into the the DOM?

Comment: People are stabbing in the dark.  Show us the rendered html for the treeview so we can see the hierarchy.

Comment: @Archer - The TreeView from ASP.NET ends up being huge and would be difficult to post everything here. That's why I tried to slim it down.

Comment: @Archer - I added the full HTML and another jQuery function I tried and it is still not removing that class.

Comment: I'm not at a PC at the minute. I'll have a look later when I get home :)

Comment: Also, is it possible that since these `<span>` classes are being added server side to the `.Text` property of the `TreeNode` object as a _hack_ to raise a flag to disable checkboxes, that ViewState is _reloading_ the structure client-side, thus overriding any client-side removal of the class attribute?

Comment: This is **exactly** the issue. The client-side script that executes this runs prior to the server side event. Even though there is no code on the postback that re-adds these classes, the server is reloading the TreeView as it was last built with the classes, thus looking like the client script is not working. I tested by placing a HTML button on screen and no postback to run the script. The result: class is gone. Let me see if calling a Client script _after_ postback to remove classes will work...

Comment: Running the client script in a `document.ready()` handler should solve that problem, but then why would you ever need the disabled class to be applied in the first place?  I'm not clear on why this class is being applied and removed in this way.  If you're causing postback then maybe you should be looking at a server-side-only solution

Comment: @Archer - Unfortunately there is no server-side way to _disable_ the checkbox in an ASP.NET TreeView control. You must add a class server-side that is then read client side to be able to run script that _can_ disable the checkbox. Problem is, that class persists too long and has undesired effects if not removed in certain situations. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078476/disabling-asp-net-treeview-checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, the remove process seems to be fine. I believe what's occurring (which you didn't illustrate) is that your selector is wrong. I assume that you are passing 'MainContent_MyTreeView' to the function EnableAllCheckBoxes. However, in jQuery to reference something by ID, you need the '#' in your selector. Either call the function so:

```
EnableAllCheckBoxes('#MainContent_MyTreeView');
```

Or modify the function like so:

```
function EnableAllCheckBoxes(treeviewClientID) {
     $('#' + treeviewClientID).removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');
  }
```

Comment: This is how it gets called so actually the seletor is present: `EnableAllCheckBoxes('#<%=MyTreeView.ClientID %>');` I tried to remove doubt about that in my description but I never actually showed this code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the class from the descendants of the list, not from the list itself.
In that case, you should use:

```
function EnableAllCheckBoxes(treeviewClientID) {
     $('span.disabledTreeviewNode', '#' + treeviewClientID).removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');
  }
```

What this means: any `span` with the CSS class `disabledTreeviewNode` that resides below `#treeviewClientID` will have the CSS class `disabledTreeviewNode` removed.

---

Let's **debug**!

Modify your function to:

```
function EnableAllCheckBoxes(treeviewClientID) {
     console.log(treeviewClientID);
     console.log($('span.disabledTreeviewNode', treeviewClientID));
     $('span.disabledTreeviewNode', treeviewClientID).removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');
  }
```

Hit F12, move to the **Console** tab and refresh the page. Verify what's logged at the console and try to troubleshoot it.

---

**EDIT**

Based on the HTML you added to the question, I'm sure that

```
$('span.disabledTreeviewNode', '#MainContent_MyTreeView').removeClass('disabledTreeviewNode');
```

Should work fine. In fact, if you open the console here at your question and run

```
$('pre.prettyprint', '#question').removeClass('prettyprint');
```

You'll see that it works as expected. It's the same logic.

Can you inspect if there's anything else going on there?

Comment: I tried this (with the exception of removing `'#'` because when the method is called that selector is present `EnableAllCheckBoxes('#<%=MyTreeView.ClientID %>');` but it still didn't work :(

Comment: @atconway What browser are you using? I've added some code to debug, see me update please.

Comment: I'm using IE10 and upon looking at the ouput in the Console tab I just see ` [object Object]` and no ability to drill down into the content. Is there another way to see the output?

Comment: @atconway Do you have Firefox or Chrome (I prefer Chrome) there? The console log will be much easier to read. What about the first log, is the ID correct?

Comment: Yes the ID was correct. In fact I added other `jQuery` that works using the ID and it was successful taking the ID out of the equation. I added the full HTML from the rendering in my OP. It's just the jQuery I'm using is not getting those `<span>` elements and removing the class.

Comment: @atconway Updated my answer, take a look please.

Comment: Look at my last comments added on the OP. I figured it out the problem; still working on solution. `jQuery` was not necessarily the issue. In fact I have it working. This issue is the server is reloading the TreeView to it's _known_ state not taking into account any client side manipulation.

Comment: @atconway Now I see, it makes sense. That was a clever observation, congrats. Let me know if I can be of any help.